# .Net Core 1.0 Thread class doesn't have Interrupt() function

Tags: c#, multithreading, .net-core

By reading the documentation on msdn I was just trying to play around with some thread class functions. But found out this strange behavior there is no interrupt function in Thread Class. I am using Visual studio 2015 and .net core 1.0 console app

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
namespace ThreadingBasicsRight
{

public class Program
{
    public static Object _lock = new Object();
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Thread t = new Thread(test1);
        t.Start();
        t.Interrupt(); 
    }
    public static void test1()
    {
        lock (_lock)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(i);
            }
            Thread.Sleep(100);
        }
    }
    public static void test2()
    {
        lock (_lock)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("process is not in a dead lock");
        }
    }
 }
}
```

Comment: Well, that's [documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/api/system.threading.thread); only `Start`, `Sleep` and `Join` are available. `Thread.Interrupt` is a mostly deprecated way of synchronization; it should come as no surprise that Core leaves it out entirely. (Even when classes exist in .NET Core, they are *not* guaranteed to have everything they have in the .NET Framework.)

Comment: Thanks that helps I think so i might be looking into the .net 4 documentation.

Comment: Do you really need a threads? Why don't use tasks?

Comment: Why would you *want* to cause an asynchronous exception in a thread? What possible use case could you have for this?

Comment: @Luaan: the thread in question can catch `ThreadInterruptedException` specifically and use it as a signal to do something (like, stop processing), saving you the need to use a separate event, lock object or what have you. (It's like `Thread.Abort`, but safe, since it only throws when the thread would enter a wait state.) That is its use case, it's just been superseded by better alternatives (like task cancellation), and there is no compelling reason for .NET Core to offer it.

Comment: @JeroenMostert I'd say it's *worse* than `Thread.Abort`, since you still have no idea where your wait states are and have no control over when it's safe to do the interrupt, and yet non-wait code will happily keep running forever. It does avoid a few of the pitfalls of `Abort`, but not really enough to be used safely anyway - and it introduces others (e.g. you call a method that swallows the exception and your signal is lost). Task cancellation doesn't do anything that wasn't available before - you have a single volatile int field with cmpexchg writes, no wait handles of any kind needed.

Comment: @Luaan: sorry, I thought you were actually *asking* "what is a possible use case" (since the OP's code doesn't actually demonstrate it effectively), I didn't get you were indirectly saying "this is always a bad idea". It wasn't my intent to start a discussion on the relative merits of `Thread.Interrupt` (or other methods of synchronization).

Comment: As beginner all comments were really help full in understanding these to primitives Abort and Interrupt and why they are a bad idea to use them :)

Comment: So what happens when you start a console app that runs a server? How would you abort this, since the console app has no built in cancellation support?